# How to write custom event log in monolog library?

Tags: laravel, monolog

I am using Laravel to build my web site.I installed monolog library to keep logging.
I want to log for click event.
how can I do this?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicks happen on front-end side.

If you want to log every page load (PHP call) you can use `App::before` in `app/filters.php` to log every request. More information on that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events).

If you want to log every click you might want to use Google Analytics' event tracking. Write some JS to handle all click events and send them to `ga`. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.please point me to how to catch the click event inside the before() function.

Comment: `App::before(function ($request) { $monolog = Logger::getMonolog(); });`

Comment: Class 'Logger' not found exception is thrown after adding the code

Comment: The facade is `Log` instead of `Logger`, but you have found out about that already, isn't it?

Comment: small problem.I want to identify click and post events separately.when I put a message in before function all the events like click,post,ect. print the same message.

Comment: found it.I got it by $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].

Comment: The goal is to -not- use Superglobals. You can get the method with `Request::method();`